# Nesting Data Frames

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, sequence

I have a function wrapping **RODBC::sqlQuery** that takes a start & end date and returns 5 columns with and roughly 1 million rows per call. I need to iterate through a list of about 60 dates storing the function's resulting data frames in a list.

What I want to know is:

1. How to pass both start and end date arguments to the function in an
   apply-style fashion
2. How to store the resulting data frames neatly (like a table of |date|data.frame.pointer|)

Here's some of the code:

```
get.data <- function(date.start, date.end) { ... }
date.range <- seq(as.Date("2009-01-01"), Sys.Date(), by="1 month")
```

And sample output:

```
get.data(date.start="2009-01-01", date.end='2009-02-01')
               date    country    oId    eId       pId
    1    2009-01-01  Australia  12345  12345     12345
    2           ...        ...    ...    ...       ...
```

Thank you for your help. I've been trying to figure out how to do this for hours to no avail.

Comment: please tag the question with appropriate language tag

Comment: @laalto Oops, thanks. I was flustered when I posted this and forgot to tag it with [r].

Comment: Do you mean that you want to call the function `get.data` multiple times, with different values of `date.start` and `date.end`? How are these values generated?

Comment: @HongOoi Yes, like `apply(get.data, c(date.range[i], date.range[i+1]))`. The values are a sequence of dates like in the `date.range` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you want, `mapply` will do the trick:

```
n <- length(date.range)
mapply(get.data, date.range[-n], date.range[-1])
```

This returns a list whose elements are the individual returned values from `get.data`. So in this case, you would get a list of data frames. That may well be the most appropriate way of storing the output, but it would depend on what you want to do with it.